# Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506) when building projects using `dotnet build`

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, clr, roslyn

When building or running tests in any C# projects from a PowerShell command line (`dotnet build` or `dotnet test`) I get a "Fatal error. Internal CLR error" with the following output:

```
MSBuild version 17.7.3+8ec440e68 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error : Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.NetCore.Analyzers.InteropServices.PlatformCompatibilityAnalyzer+<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<AnalyzeOperationBlock>b__1(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.OperationBlockAnalysisContext) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerExecutor+<>c__54`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].<ExecuteBlockActions>b__54_1(System.ValueTuple`2<System.Action`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.OperationBlockAnalysisContext>,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.OperationBlockAnalysisContext>) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerExecutor.ExecuteAndCatchIfThrows_NoLock[[System.ValueTuple`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.OperationBlockAnalysisContext, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAnalyzer, System.Action`1<System.ValueTuple`2<System.__Canon,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.OperationBlockAnalysisContext>>, System.ValueTuple`2<System.__Canon,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.OperationBlockAnalysisContext>, System.Nullable`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalysisContextInfo>, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerExecutor.ExecuteAndCatchIfThrows[[System.ValueTuple`2[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.OperationBlockAnalysisContext, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAnalyzer, System.Action`1<System.ValueTuple`2<System.__Canon,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.OperationBlockAnalysisContext>>, System.ValueTuple`2<System.__Canon,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.OperationBlockAnalysisContext>, System.Nullable`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalysisContextInfo>, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerExecutor.ExecuteBlockActions[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PooledObjects.PooledHashSet`1<System.__Canon>, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAnalyzer, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SemanticModel, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IOperation>, System.Action`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostic>, System.Func`3<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostic,System.Threading.CancellationToken,Boolean>, System.Nullable`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextSpan>, Boolean, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerExecutor.ExecuteBlockActionsCore[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.DiagnosticAnalyzer, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<System.__Canon>, System.Func`2<System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<System.__Canon>,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>>, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SemanticModel, System.Func`2<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxNode,Int32>, System.Nullable`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Text.TextSpan>, Boolean, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver`1+<>c__DisplayClass11_0[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxKind, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].<ExecuteDeclaringReferenceActions>g__executeOperationsBlockActions|6(System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IOperation>, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IOperation>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<ExecutableCodeBlockAnalyzerActions<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxKind>>) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver`1+<>c__DisplayClass11_0[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxKind, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].<ExecuteDeclaringReferenceActions>g__executeExecutableCodeActions|2() [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver`1[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxKind, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].ExecuteDeclaringReferenceActions(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxReference, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.SymbolDeclaredCompilationEvent, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalysisScope, GroupedAnalyzerActions<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxKind>, GroupedAnalyzerActions<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxKind>, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver`1[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxKind, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].ExecuteDeclaringReferenceActions(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.SymbolDeclaredCompilationEvent, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalysisScope, Boolean, IGroupedAnalyzerActions, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver+<TryProcessSymbolDeclaredAsync>d__137.MoveNext() [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver+<TryProcessSymbolDeclaredAsync>d__137, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<TryProcessSymbolDeclaredAsync>d__137 ByRef) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver.TryProcessSymbolDeclaredAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.SymbolDeclaredCompilationEvent, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalysisScope, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver+<TryProcessEventCoreAsync>d__136.MoveNext() [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver+<TryProcessEventCoreAsync>d__136, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<TryProcessEventCoreAsync>d__136 ByRef) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver.TryProcessEventCoreAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.CompilationEvent, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalysisScope, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver+<ProcessEventAsync>d__134.MoveNext() [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver+<ProcessEventAsync>d__134, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]](<ProcessEventAsync>d__134 ByRef) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver.ProcessEventAsync(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.CompilationEvent, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalysisScope, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver+<ProcessCompilationEventsCoreAsync>d__133.MoveNext() [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(System.Threading.Thread, System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerDriver+<ProcessCompilationEventsCoreAsync>d__133, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]].MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread) [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.401\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool+WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart() [C:\<redacted>\test-build.csproj]
```

- This applies to *any* project, so I can do `dotnet new console` followed by `dotnet build` and get the error
- If I start a separate Command Prompt window (cmd.exe) and type `dotnet build` the build will succeed without error, and if I after doing that switch back to the PowerShell window and re-issue the `dotnet build` command, it succeeds without any errors
- Visual Studio builds works as expected (does not give the error)
- I get the same error when issuing `dotnet build` from a "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022" window
- I have the (currently) latest .NET version installed (7.0.401, commit eb26aacfec), and this problem started some versions ago. The PowerShell version is 7.3.7 Core
- I'm experiencing the same problem on two separate machines

I've overcome so far by starting a new cmd.exe window as mentioned and then switch back to PowerShell, but its getting a bit tedious.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to narrow the cause down: if you run `cmd /c dotnet build` directly from PowerShell, does it crash too? If you start your PowerShell session with `pwsh -NoProfile`, does the crash still occur?

Comment: @mklement0, both of these give the same error

Comment: I see. Does the crash also occur when you run from Windows PowerShell (`powershell.exe`)?

Comment: @mklement0, yes it does

Answer (score 3):

That is likely a bug on Microsoft side that you should report to Microsoft. I'd start by opening an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=bug-report.md&title=) with repro steps. It will get routed to the correct team if needed (which could end up being dotnet/runtime).

Comment: Added issue in roslyn-analyzers repository: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/6965

Answer (score 0):

For me this was resolved by adding the following to `$PROFILE`:

```
rm ENV:DOTNET_TieredCompilation
rm ENV:COMPlus_TieredCompilation
```

I don't know who or what added these environment variables and set them to `0`, but removing them altogether, or resetting them to default (`1`) does the trick for me.

Comment: See also https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/91695